# Php character count without spaces and html tags

Tags: php, text, count, character

I want to count characters in a text like Microsoft Word.

```
<p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Tom's farm. 12th century.</p>
```

12th -> 'th' is a special character, under the number 12.

How can I do that in **PHP**?

Comment: Strip the tags and whitespace then count. I don't understand what you mean about `th` and the `12`. Example: https://eval.in/665455.

Comment: I can't understand your question exactly. Can you show any example?

Comment: Why would you wanna do something so simple using php? You could use Jquery instead. PHP server side scripting you don't have to do simple things like this with php sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is;

```
    $content = 'Some Text...';

    $trim = strip_tags($content);
    $trim=str_replace([" ","\n","\t","&ndash;","&rsquo;","&#39;","&quot;","&nbsp;"], '', $trim);

    $totalCharacter = strlen(utf8_decode($trim));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "<p><b>Lorem Ipsum</b> is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.Tom's farm. 12th century.</p>";
$string = strip_tags($string);
$string = preg_replace("/\s/", "", $string);
$character_count = strlen($string);
```

If there is a th Unicode character, strlen will probably count it as two characters. Then you should maybe have a look on mb_strlen.

Comment: `th` is not a multibyte character (or not in the provided example). Also regex would process faster with quantifier I think.

Comment: but maybe he gets the text from somewhere and just didnt know how to show it here. I just mentioned it, in case he will use multibyte characters. Since I'm not an expert in regex'es. You mean with would process faster? preg_replace("/\s*/", "", $string);

Comment: Yes `*` or `+`. with the single character you are replacing them all individually. `mb_strlen` and `strlen` will both count `th` as 2 characters, because it is 2 characters.